# convert db2 backup to usable format (text file of some sort)

Tags: db2

I've received six DB2 backup images, however I don't have access to DB2. Is there any way to convert these images to text files or some usable format?

Comment: No you cannot convert DB2 backup images to anything. You can install a trial version of DB2 and restore the backup though. After that you'll be able to export data in whatever format you prefer.

Comment: Make sure you know what version of DB2 was used to create the backup. There are certain limitations for cross-platform (e.g. Windows to Linux) or cross-version restore.